# Loading .rb files in Mac OS IRB

Tags: ruby, git, bash, environment, irb

I'm just staring out with Ruby.  I followed a tutorial to set up Ruby environment on my Mac OS.  Then, I created a file named 'personal_chef.rb' in Sublime Text and saved it to a folder I created.  Next went to IRB and tried "load 'personal_chef.rb'" and got the error:

*-bash: load: command not found*

I think it might have to do with how I switched my PATH when installing a new version of git during Environment setup. (I did that by following their instructions and typing: 'echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile').

Can someone please help explain what is happening and how I can fix it?  Basically I want to be able to create a file in Sublime Text, save it, then load it in IRB.

(I am running Mac OS 10.7.5, using Sublime Text 2.0.2 and using Terminal.app for IRB).

Thanks!

Comment: Can you describe what you mean exactly when you say you "went to IRB"?

Comment: Are you certain that you actually needed to modify your `~/.bash_profile`? Chances are good that `/usr/local/bin` was *already* in your `PATH` and adding it again is just redundant.

Comment: If you got the error `bash: load: command not found` it sounds like you entered the command in `bash`, not `irb`.

Comment: Sure.  For "went to IRB" I just mean I typed "irb" at the command prompt in terminal.app .  I don't know if I needed to modify my ~bash, but the instructions on setting the environment said that I wouldn't be able to see if I had the latest version of Git unless I asked it to look in a different PATH than usr/bin; so they had us type in "echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile" so it looks there first.  So, how do I enter the command in irb instead of bash?  I thought I was doing that by entering "irb" at the prompt.  Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 2):

This is how you load the file:

First, make sure you enter the `irb` command from within the same directory you saved 'personal_chef.rb'.

This means that if you saved it to your desktop, you would type  `~/desktop`

You'll know you're in irb if your command line beings with  `irb(main)`

Next simply type  `load 'personal_chef.rb'`

If you successfully loaded the file the load method will return true.

Comment: Thanks.  So I typed "irb" at the prompt and that was fine.  Then I asked it to load 'personal_chef.rb' and got:                2.0.0p247 :001 > load '~desktop/personal_chef.rb'
ArgumentError: user desktop doesn't exist
 from (irb):1:in `load'
 from (irb):1
 from /Users/shrmacbook/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
2.0.0p247 :002 >.  So it still didn't work.  Sorry to be that gy but still would love some help with this. Thanks.

Comment: Nevermind!  I solved it: apparently since my .rb file didn't have any information, it wasn't loading in IRB.  The next step of the (poorly written) tutorial had me make a class and a method, re-save it and voila! It opened in irb.  But Everyone's advice here taught me a few extra things that I wouldn't have other wise known.  Thanks all.